# COUNTIFS and 2 Dimensional Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table full of information in the following format:

[image]

I made a table that tries to create a relationship between the columns; for example, the number of people in Support that are also in Security (should return 2)

As a formula, I wrote the following

> COUNTIFS($A$2:$AA$49,$A53,$A$2:$AA$49,D$52)

Where *$A$2:$AA$49* is the range of the whole data, and *$A53* and *D$52* is the condition it should equate to.

Yet, no matter what I try, I always yield 0, stating I'm referring to a blank cell.

The following is the format I want to place it in. Assume *$A53* and *D$52* are Support and Implementation, respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the columns, you can do that with INDEX/MATCH, i.e.

`=COUNTIFS(INDEX($A$2:$AA$49,0,MATCH($A53,$A$1:$AA$1,0)),$A53,INDEX($A$2:$AA$49,0,MATCH(D$52,$A$1:$AA$1,0)),D$52)`

Note: header has to equal cell contents so "Other Member" header needs to become "Other" to match contents (or vice versa)

Comment: Wow, yours is much cleaner, what I made was the following:

'=COUNTIFS("CHAR(64+(MATCH($A53,$A$1:$AA$1,0)))&2&":"&CHAR(64+(MATCH($A53,$A$1:$AA$1,0)))&49",$A53,CHAR(64+(MATCH(C$52,$A$1:$AA$1,0)))&2&":"&CHAR(64+(MATCH(C$52,$A$1:$AA$1,0)))&49,C$52)'


Extremely messy! Thank you for your help!